# why doesn't my session work after redirecting?

Tags: php, session

One month ago,My session didn't keep its values between my own web pages, so by changing file types from **UTF-8** to **UTF8-Without BOM** my problem solved.
Now I am using a Bank web service that I am calling its methods successfully.by posting a form my page redirects to bank's page,after payment and redirecting to my site,my session array is empty!!!!

my session doesn't keep its values...why?

before redirecting(**process1.php**):

```
<?php
session_start(); // first line and without space
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">     
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $("form").submit();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $_SESSION['price']=1000;
            $_SESSION['username']="14276912";
            $_SESSION['password']="874593a";
            $_SESSION['ReturnURL']="www.mysite.com/process3.php";
            $params=array(//parameters);
            $client=new SoapClient("https://bankname.com/MerchantUtility.asmx?wsdl");
            $result=$client->__soapCall('bpPayRequest', array($params));                                     
            $RefId=$result[0];
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="https://bankname.com/pgwchannel/startpay">
            <input name="RefId" value="<?php echo $RefId?>" type="hidden"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

after comeback from redirected page(**process2.php**):

```
<?php
session_start(); // first line and without space
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

Var_dump shows  **array(0) { }**
I am confused really.

Comment: do you submit to other page?

Comment: yes I post the form to Bank's gatway from **process2.php**,so process2.php redirects to Bank's payment page.after pay operation on Bank side,the Bank posts result to my **process3.php** and redirect to it.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i try using localhost and its work. This is simple value passing code.

this is first page:

```
<?php
session_start();
            $_SESSION['price']=1000;
            $_SESSION['username']="14276912";
            $_SESSION['password']="874593a";
?>

<form method="post" action="a.php">
            <input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit"/>
        </form>
```

this is targeting page:

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

and this is result :

```
array(3) { ["price"]=> int(1000) ["username"]=> string(8) "14276912" ["password"]=> string(7) "874593a" }
```

Comment: what problem do you get?